# send data to server

Tags: php, jquery, forms, button

so heres the thing. I have noticed on websites that instead of having `<input type="submit">` they have `<button type="button">` and when user clicks on the button it goes to a new page such as Edit page. how can it be done?

I mean i do know jquery.form submit function which when user clicks on a button type submit it goes to the directed page.

but they dont use `<input type="submit">` , how can it be done ?
how can send data like to edit.php when user clicks on

```
<button type="button" class="me" onclick=";return false;" role="button">
```

without using ajax!

Comment: Are you sure they aren't using `<button type="submit">`?

Answer (score 0):

They either use [javascript redirect](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php) or they use [manual javascript submit function](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there is an event handler that is attached that could handle business logic

Answer (score 0):

You can even use this button to submit a form like this.

```
$('button').click(function(){

   $(this).closest('form').submit();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this to send data without jquery and ajax :

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
        var xmlHttp = null;

        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
        xmlHttp.send( null );
        alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
}
```

mitoni aslan be response tavajoh nakoni va safaro redirect koni be ye safeye jadid.